# remove cart functionality from nopcommerce

Tags: asp.net, nopcommerce

I want to develop a dynamic web page where admin can  add their product specification and images and other promotio  offers.
I read about nopcommerce shopping cart with asp.net.I want to know to remove cart functionality from nopcommerce to achieve my goal..Or is it better to use pure coding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nopCommerce is an **e-Commerce** solution. Without Cart Functionality, it will be like a Photographer without a Camera !

If you simply want dynamic content displayed on a page, then go for a CMS, I personally like [Umbraco](http://umbraco.org/), but that has quite a steep learning curve.

Answer (score 4):

In admin: You go to Configuration->Access Control List

Then just simply uncheck "Public store. Enable shopping cart"

And in regards to Ciwan's comments, I found many of my clients want their site like this. Such as a liquor store that simply wants to display prices but not sell online.

Answer (score 1):

you need do some code fixes set ShoppingCartEnabled = false in

```
//Nop.Web/Controller/CommonController
   In HeaderLinks Action
```

and second one to disable to "Add To Cart" button by setting

```
//Nop.Web/Controller/CatlogController 
 In PrepareProductVariantModel method
```

you can also do all these setting rom admin area Admin-> Configuration-> Setting -> AllSetting 
in admin it will do all changes tempery. if you want to do it permanently  then modified

```
InstalltionService (Nop.Service/Installtion/InstalltionService.cs)
```

Note:This is applicable to version 2.0 to 2.65